# Create post reaction using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to generate a jQuery code with post review functionality. What I want to create looks like the image below:

[image]

Like and dislike buttons will be highlighted each time they are clicked. The reaction will be stored locally using localStorage.

This is my HTML code:

```html
<div class="reaction-post" data-id="123456">
      <div class="like" data-title="like">Like</div>
      <div class="dislike" data-title="dislike">Dislike</div>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery code:

```js
$(function(){
    $('.reaction-post div').click(function(){
        var lod = $(this).attr('data-title');
        var idr = $('.reaction-post').attr('data-id');       
        localStorage.setItem(idr,lod);
        var ratinghis = localStorage.getItem(idr);
        $('.reaction-post').addClass(ratinghis);     
    });
});
```

My problem is I don't know how to removeClass after click to another option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could add something like this at the start of the "click" handler:

> $(".reaction-post").removeClass("dislike like");

This will, on a like/dislike button click, remove all "like" or "dislike" class to your .reaction-post, and then your script applies a new one depending on the clicked button.

Note: if you have many elements like this on your page (DOM) (many like and dislike button), you may want to restrict the class manipulation to the clicked element.

Edit: your code could look like this (not tested, but you get the idea):

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.reaction-post div').click(function(){
        var likable_element = $(this).parent(); //the .reaction-post, easier to manager multiple likeable element on the same page
        likable_element.removeClass("dislike like");
        
        var lod = $(this).attr('data-title');
        var idr = likable_element.attr('data-id');       
        localStorage.setItem(idr,lod);
        var ratinghis = localStorage.getItem(idr);
        likable_element.addClass(ratinghis);     
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I still have a question as to whether my way of using localStorage can cause the evaluations to still be valid after the page reloads?

Comment: Yes, your values should still be in the LocalStorage after a refresh. Unless you update it somewhere else in-between.